# How to count the consecutive duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We have two columns in a table customer in which we have customer id and the service id in those. So, every customer using multiple services, we have to find the maximum count of the consecutive services used by the customers.

```
create table customer(id int not null auto_increment,customerid varchar(20), serviceid varchar(20),primary key(id));

insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nitesh','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nitesh','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nitesh','Landline');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nitesh','Broadband');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nitesh','Mobile');

insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nishant','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nishant','Landline');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nishant','Landline');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nishant','Landline');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Nishant','Broadband');

insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Soe','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Soe','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Soe','Landline');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Soe','Broadband');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Soe','Mobile');
```

I have to count the maximum service used by the customer consecutively.

**Output:**

```
Customerid|Serviceid|ServiceidCount
----------------------------------

Nitesh|Mobile|2
Nishant|Landline|3
Soe|Mobile|2
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column specifying the ordering, your question has no meaning.

Comment: And how exactly can we know the order?

Comment: ...so you need another column (a date, an ID...)

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have a column that specifies the ordering, say `id`.

Then you can do this using variables:

```
select customer, max(rn) as serviceidcnt,
       substring_index(group_concat(serviceid order by rn desc)) as serviceid
from (select c.*,
             (@rn := if(@cs = concat_ws(':', customerid, serviceid), @rn + 1,
                        if(@cs := concat_ws(':', customerid, serviceid), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from customer c cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @cs := '') params
      order by c.customer, ??
     ) cs
group by customer;
```

The `??` is for the column used for ordering.

Note:  Getting the service id requires using a MySQL "hack" that depends on `group_concat()`.  By default this is limited to an internal buffer size of about 1000 bytes.  This can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated version**

You can try following query.  It uses mysql variables to check for consecutive changes in columns **customerid** and **serviceid**.

```
    SELECT customerid, serviceid, MAX(R)+1 AS ServiceIdCount
FROM (SELECT c.customerid, c.serviceid
    , CASE WHEN @s=CONCAT(customerid,'|',serviceid) THEN @r:=@r+1 ELSE @r:=0 END AS R
    , @s:=CONCAT(customerid,'|',serviceid) AS S
    FROM customer c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:=0, @s:='') d
     ORDER BY id
    ) e 
WHERE R>0
GROUP BY customerid, serviceid;
```

Added sample data (other than yours):

```
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Mark','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Mark','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Mark','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Mark','Landline');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Mark','Mobile');
insert into customer(customerid,serviceid) values('Mark','Mobile');
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+----------------+
| customerid | serviceid | ServiceIdCount |
+------------+-----------+----------------+
| Mark       | Mobile    |              3 |
| Nishant    | Landline  |              3 |
| Nitesh     | Mobile    |              2 |
| Soe        | Mobile    |              2 |
+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: @NiteshKataria query modified to get MAX consecutives.