# How to select a dynamic number of rows in MySQL without breaking sequential userids

Tags: mysql

**BACKGROUND:** We have a table we use to queue actions that need to be completed in order by id, but we need to grab small groups to process without breaking up the sequential userids.

Using the data set below where we want to select roughly 10 rows (in reality it's much more than this) that have not been completed.

**THE QUESTION:**  How to select a dynamic number of rows in MySQL without breaking sequential userids?

BTW, I have reviewed the following questions that don't really illuminate how to accomplish my specific task.

- [How to count the consecutive duplicate rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445585/how-to-count-the-consecutive-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)
- [Arrange duplicates and number the records in a sequence - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743696/arrange-duplicates-and-number-the-records-in-a-sequence-mysql)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188775/selecting-consecutive-rows-with-same-values
- [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Dear Moderator: this is not applicable, and my question is not duplicate.  My question has nothing to do with delimited lists. Our data is not delimited.)

Notice in the faulty example query below that it cuts off 2 rows for userid 1083.  We set a limit to 10, yes. So the query did what it should. However, how do we 'pick up' the next 2 for userid 1083, or leave off the last 2 userid 1083 which would then be selected as part of the next select of uncompleted actions?

**EXAMPLE QUERY (faulty):**

```
SELECT id, userid, action_id, specific_id, index_id, internal_id, extra_data, completed
      FROM test_table
      WHERE completed = 0
      ORDER BY id LIMIT 10
```

**EXAMPLE RESULT (faulty):**

```
    id  userid  action_id  specific_id  index_id  internal_id  extra_data  completed  
------  ------  ---------  -----------  --------  -----------  ----------  -----------
     5    1081         22  1081                4            2  12                    0
     6    1081         22  1081                4            2  11                    0
     7    1081         41  1081               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
     8    1081         41  1081               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
     9    1082         22  1082                4            2  12                    0
    10    1082         22  1082                4            2  11                    0
    11    1082         41  1082               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
    12    1082         41  1082               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
    13    1083         22  1083                4            2  12                    0
    14    1083         22  1083                4            2  11                    0
```

---

**ACCEPTABLE RESULTS**

*ACCEPTABLE EXAMPLE 1:*

```
    id  userid  action_id  specific_id  index_id  internal_id  extra_data  completed  
------  ------  ---------  -----------  --------  -----------  ----------  -----------
     5    1081         22  1081                4            2  12                    0
     6    1081         22  1081                4            2  11                    0
     7    1081         41  1081               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
     8    1081         41  1081               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
     9    1082         22  1082                4            2  12                    0
    10    1082         22  1082                4            2  11                    0
    11    1082         41  1082               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
    12    1082         41  1082               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
    13    1083         22  1083                4            2  12                    0
    14    1083         22  1083                4            2  11                    0
    15    1083         41  1083               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
    16    1083         41  1083               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
```

**OR**

*ACCEPTABLE EXAMPLE 2:*

```
    id  userid  action_id  specific_id  index_id  internal_id  extra_data  completed  
------  ------  ---------  -----------  --------  -----------  ----------  -----------
     5    1081         22  1081                4            2  12                    0
     6    1081         22  1081                4            2  11                    0
     7    1081         41  1081               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
     8    1081         41  1081               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
     9    1082         22  1082                4            2  12                    0
    10    1082         22  1082                4            2  11                    0
    11    1082         41  1082               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
    12    1082         41  1082               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
```

---

**TEST DATA SET**

```
    id  userid  action_id  specific_id  index_id  internal_id  extra_data  completed  
------  ------  ---------  -----------  --------  -----------  ----------  -----------
     1    1080         22  1080                4            2  12                    1
     2    1080         22  1080                4            2  11                    1
     3    1080         41  1080               21            2  1,6,1,5               1
     4    1080         41  1080               21            2  2,6,2,1               1
     5    1081         22  1081                4            2  12                    0
     6    1081         22  1081                4            2  11                    0
     7    1081         41  1081               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
     8    1081         41  1081               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
     9    1082         22  1082                4            2  12                    0
    10    1082         22  1082                4            2  11                    0
    11    1082         41  1082               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
    12    1082         41  1082               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
    13    1083         22  1083                4            2  12                    0
    14    1083         22  1083                4            2  11                    0
    15    1083         41  1083               21            2  1,6,1,5               0
    16    1083         41  1083               21            2  2,6,2,1               0
    17     394         49  1                   2           99                        0
    18     394         40  1                   3            9                        0
    19     394         18  1                   3            9  1                     0
    20       3         49  2                   2           99                        0
    21     394         49  3                   2           99                        0
    22     394         49  4                   2           99                        0
    23       3         40  3                   3            9                        0
    24       3         18  3                   3            9  1                     0
    25       3         51  3                   3            9                        0
    26       3         22  2                   5           20  9                     0
```

Use this to build the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `id` INT (11),
    `userid` INT (11),
    `action_id` INT (11),
    `specific_id` VARCHAR (250),
    `index_id` INT (11),
    `internal_id` INT (11),
    `extra_data` VARCHAR (250),
    `completed` INT (11)
); 
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('1','1080','22','1080','4','2','12','1');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('2','1080','22','1080','4','2','11','1');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('3','1080','41','1080','21','2','1,6,1,5','1');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('4','1080','41','1080','21','2','2,6,2,1','1');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('5','1081','22','1081','4','2','12','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('6','1081','22','1081','4','2','11','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('7','1081','41','1081','21','2','1,6,1,5','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('8','1081','41','1081','21','2','2,6,2,1','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('9','1082','22','1082','4','2','12','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('10','1082','22','1082','4','2','11','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('11','1082','41','1082','21','2','1,6,1,5','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('12','1082','41','1082','21','2','2,6,2,1','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('13','1083','22','1083','4','2','12','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('14','1083','22','1083','4','2','11','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('15','1083','41','1083','21','2','1,6,1,5','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('16','1083','41','1083','21','2','2,6,2,1','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('17','394','49','1','2','99','','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('18','394','40','1','3','9','','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('19','394','18','1','3','9','1','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('20','3','49','2','2','99','','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('21','394','49','3','2','99','','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('22','394','49','4','2','99','','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('23','3','40','3','3','9','','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('24','3','18','3','3','9','1','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('25','3','51','3','3','9','','0');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `userid`, `action_id`, `specific_id`, `index_id`, `internal_id`, `extra_data`, `completed`) VALUES('26','3','22','2','5','20','9','0');
```

Comment: there are a lot of functionnality questions that I could ask about the data input and how it is organized that could change how you might want to handle this problem. I would try selecting rows in relation to the userid and put it on a counter; this way you would process one user at a time.

Comment: @strawberry you've incorrectly marked this question as duplicate. The question you reference has nothing to do with my question.  Why do you think a question about delimited lists stored in a DB relates to my question about selecting a dynamic number of rows based on sequential data?